# Google Sheets: How to automatically insert a word into a cell on a new row detected?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have searched high and low but I have been unable to find an answer (I am sure I am not explaining it right)

I have a Google Sheet that have multiple sheets (tabs) labeled TabA, TabB and TabC.

On this Google Sheet, I submit a slash command on Slack, which then auto-fills a row on one of the tabs using apps script.

What I am trying to do is simply insert a word called TabA into a specific cell each time a new row has been detected. And insert a word called TabB when a new row has been made on TabB sheet etc.

I am sure I just am typing my questions wrong which is why I am unable to find an answer.

I am not actually sure which part of the code posts to the sheet, I think it is this?

````
  if(sheetName) {
    sheetName = sheetName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sheetName.slice(1)
  } else {
    sheetName = "Current"
  }

  // Find sheet
  var sheetFlag = false;
  for (var r = 1; r < settings.length; r++) {
    if (settings[r][1] == channelID) {
      var sheetID = settings[r][2];
      var targetChannelID = settings[r][4];
      var title = settings[r][0];
      sheetFlag = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (sheetFlag) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if(!sheet) {
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).insertSheet(sheetName);
    }

    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    var slackDetails = ["", "", text1, "","","","","",realName, new Date(),title,text2];

    // paste the slack details to the sheet
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,slackDetails.length).setValues([slackDetails]);```
Thank you in advance
````

Comment: Can you provide your current script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: There is no trigger that will detect a row being added by a script.  It only detects user changes.

Comment: As Cooper said, there is no trigger to track changes made by a script. Would using a time-based trigger that runs every minute to check if there are changes be a valid workaround?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Would I hit rate limits if I had that trigger running every minute?
I could have it set to run once an hour or even once a day and it wouldn't be an issue if you had a work around?

Comment: @Vestipial `insert a word called TabA into a specific cell` which cell are you talking about?  Is it always the same one, in the sense that it gets overwritten every time the sheet has new rows? Or it gets written in the first empty row? Is it located in a different sheet (not TabA, TabB or TabC). Finally, it is the same cell for all sheets? (TabA, TabB, TabC).

Comment: @imblichus So it will be placed into an empty cell each time a new row is created, the cell will be the same on each tab (eg column K2, K3, K4 etc) and it wont be located on a different sheet.. it will be located on each sheet.

I know that I can just Write a word, and drag it down 1000 rows for example, but I have an auto archive script, so if I forget to add more rows, it will archive without an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to:

- Keep track of new rows that are added to each sheet in your spreadsheet (`TabA`, `TabB`, `TabC`).
- Write the name of the sheet **in successive rows of column D of each sheet every time news rows are detected**.

As you were told in the comments, Apps Script has no triggers to track changes made to the spreadsheet by a script. For example, [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger "runs automatically when **a user** changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet".

#### Workaround (time-based trigger and script properties):

A possible workaround to this limitation is using a time-based trigger that will fire a function periodically. You can create this trigger [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), by running this function once:

```js
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("trackRows")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
}
```

This will fire the function `trackRows` every minute. This function's purpose is to track changes to each sheet rows since last time it was fired (in this example, 1 minute ago) and write the sheet name to a certain cell if the sheet has more rows with content than during last execution.

To accomplish this, you can use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service), which lets you store key-value pairs and use them in later executions.

The function `trackRows` could be something along the following lines:

```js
function trackRows() {
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your-spreadsheet-id"); // Please change accordingly
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    var currentRows = sheet.getLastRow();
    var oldRows = props.getProperty(sheetName);
    if (currentRows > oldRows) {
      var firstRow = 2;
      var column = 4;
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
      var rowIndex = sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, numRows).getValues().filter(function(value) {
        return value[0] !== "";
      }).length;
      var cell = sheet.getRange(rowIndex + firstRow, column);
      cell.setValue(sheetName);
    }
    props.setProperty(sheetName, currentRows);
  });
}
```

This function does the following:

- Retrieve the script properties that were stored in previous executions.
- Get all the sheets in the spreadsheet.
- Check the last row with content in each sheet (via [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())), and compare the value with the one previously stored in script properties.
- If the current last row is higher than the one stored in properties, write the sheet name **in the first empty row of column D of the corresponding (starting at D2)**.
- Store the current last row in script properties.

#### Notes:

- The script is adding the sheet name to the first empty row of column D **once**, if it detects that new rows were added. It's not taking into account **how many** rows were added since last execution, it only considers **if** rows were added. This could easily be changed though, if that's what you wanted.
- If you want to start from fresh, it would be useful to delete all previously stored properties. To do that, you could run this function once:

```js
function deleteProps() {
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  props.deleteAllProperties();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#methods)
- [Class PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for trying to help here.
I didnt quite understand but i did activate the trigger and than tried various combinations.. at one point, I got it to stagger all of the sheet names on a single sheet but I am unable to reproduce that to refine it now :( 

I took some screenshots to maybe help explain if you could possibly take a look?

https://imgur.com/a/m7AGStL

Thanks again!

Comment: @Vestipial I updated my answer based on your comments, including an updated code. Let me know if that works for you!